# toggle sliders on/off with radio button in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I want to toggle off sliders when a radiobutton is pressed, and toggle them on when the other is pressed:

[image]

Anyways, when I click on toggle off I want the label, sliders and textfields to not be able to be selected. and when you click on Toggle on you can select the sliders etc again.

I get that I need to use ToggleGroup, but not sure how I would go about toggling off the sliders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use a single CheckBox for this UI rather than multiple radio buttons, then you can just bind your slider pane's disable property to the selected property of the CheckBox, but I'll just give an answer here for the UI you have displayed.

[image: on] [image: off]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToggleSetup extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        RadioButton on = new RadioButton("on");
        RadioButton off = new RadioButton("off");
        ToggleGroup toggleState = new ToggleGroup();
        on.setToggleGroup(toggleState);
        off.setToggleGroup(toggleState);
        toggleState.selectToggle(on);

        VBox sliderPane = new VBox(
                10,
                new Slider(),
                new Slider(),
                new Slider()
        );

        sliderPane.disableProperty().bind(
                Bindings.equal(off, toggleState.selectedToggleProperty())
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, on, off, sliderPane);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```